# Append a value in Struct in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift3

So I have a struct in my BaseViewController

```
struct NewUserStruct {
    var firstName: String = "Default First Name"
    var lastName: String = "Default Last Name"
}
```

I then use this in the sending VC

```
let firstNameReg = inputFirstName.text
    let lastNameReg = inputLastName.text

    let newuser = NewUserStruct(firstName: firstNameReg!, lastName: lastNameReg!)
    print(newuser.firstName)
    print(newuser.lastName)
```

This works fine and prints the first and last name. I dont think I am saving this to the struct though! as when i call the struct in the final VC:

```
let newuser = NewUserStruct()
    let firstNameLog = newuser.firstName
    print(newuser.firstName)
```

It prints the Default First Name string I set in the BaseViewController. How do I append the struct with the values in the sending VC?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You created new instance of user with `NewUserStruct()` then of course it print default value, if you want to use the `newuser ` that you created on the sending VC you have to send it to final VC

Comment: how do you passes data between view controllers

Comment: Thats what I made the Struct in the baseviewcontroller for. To store the variables values. I guess I am making a new instance when I actually want to append the existing one.

Comment: @Thegasman2000 Are you sure having defaults like `"Default First Name"` and `"Default Last Name"` makes sense to have?

Comment: Just for testing. The api I am sending the data too sorts the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of passing values(instances) from one controller to another. if you want to use the `newuser` instance values in other controller you must have to pass it from one controller to another   using `prepareForSegue` but you are creating new instance NewUserStruct() in another controller  or you can make shared properties using `static` or use them everywhere.

```
struct NewUserStruct {
 static var firstName: String = "Default First Name" 
 static var lastName: String = "Default Last Name"
} 

NewUserStruct.firstName = "new name"
```

in another controller

```
 print(NewUserStruct.firstName) // new name
```

Comment: @Thegasman2000 This only works if you only ever need one `NewUserStruct`

Comment: Yep it to add a new registration at the start of the app, so there is only on instance ever.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also user structure variable directly to save value and use in another ViewController like below**

```
struct NewUserStruct {
    static var newUserDetails: NewUserStruct = NewUserStruct()

    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}
```

**You can assign value like this**

```
NewUserStruct.newUserDetails.firstName = "ABC"
NewUserStruct.newUserDetails.lastName = "XYZ"
```

**and you can get this value in another view like this**

```
print(NewUserStruct.newUserDetails.firstName)
```

**You can reset it's value when your requirement is done**

```
NewUserStruct.newUserDetails = NewUserStruct()
```